# How can I pass values from a controller class to a NSView class?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsview

My question is about drawing a Cartesian diagram, that I have to create with some values calculated in my class "controller".
I wrote this in the file .m of my class controller:

(view1 is the istance of the NSView class )

```
for (time=1;time<=duration;time++){
    ....
    ...
    [view1 setValues:True];
    ...
}
```

and in the file .m of my NSView class:

```
-(void)setValues:(float)val{
    int i=1;
    list[i]=val;
    //NSLog(@" %f",list[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Now, how can I pass those values (the array that I created with values that I passed from my controller class) to  "drawRect"?

---

EDIT:

```
@interface viewShapes1 : NSView {
    float list[480];
}

-(void)setValues:(float)val;
-(float*)getList;

@end
```

---

```
#import "viewShapes1.h"

@implementation viewShapes1

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)setValues:(float)val {
    int i=1;
    list[i]=val;
    i++;
}

-(float*)getList {
    return list;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    float*ptr=[self getList];

    for(int i=1;i<=480;i++){
        //element of array:
        NSLog(@"%f",ptr[i]);
    }

   [...]
}
```

---

```
#import "controller.h"

[...]


-(IBAction)start:(id)sender
{

    [...]

    for(time=1;time<=duration;time=time+1)
    {
       [...]

       [view1 setValues:myValue];

       [...]
    }
}
```

the problem is that drawRect seems to not receive the values..

Comment: implement a delegate protocol.

Comment: do you initialize i in the for loop?  also, I disagree with @AnoopVaidya.  It looks like an ivar list holds the values being passed to setValues.  Just refer to list in drawRect.

Comment: @danh: y disagree, i guess he wants to pass view1

Comment: also  `i` is and always will be `1`

Comment: mmh i increas his value every time ,I don't think it's the problem,the problem is that in  "drawrect"i don't know how to read the values,because if I write  for example NSLog(@" %f",lista[5]);it gives me 0!

Comment: @danh how can i refer to list in drawRect?

Comment: Please post the code where you declare and initialize list.

Comment: @interface viewShapes1 : NSView {                                 float list[480];}

Comment: Is this ios code?  If so, the view should be a UIView, not NSView.

Comment: no,this is for mac os,I don't know why someoneput the wrong tag

Comment: @danh I wrote other things up there, could you give me a sugestion?

Comment: @bebe - I wish I could, but I might steer you wrong.  My knowledge is in iOS.

Comment: @anoop-vaidya is right. You declared i inside the method setValues:, so all changes you make to it are lost after the method exits.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial solution. I have had the same problem.

You should check the Object ID (I assume). You're certainly sending the message to the wrong object - that is my problem at least. Try to get the ID's of both objects - if they are the same, perfect.

in view:

```
Nslog(@"%@",self);
```

in class controller:

```
NSLog(@"%@",view1);
```